# EmberJS 4.2 + SocketIO 4 setup

Tags: javascript, websocket, ember.js, socket.io, event-handling

In my application, when I refresh the page, sometime I can't able to get data with SocketIO.

I think the event emitter was triggered before socket connecting to server.

**SocketIO Code:**

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

export default class SocketIoService extends Service {

  @action io() {
    return io('http://localhost:3030', {});
  }
}
```

**Data receiving Code:**

```
export default class DataService extends Service {
  @service('socket-io') socket;

  @tracked data;

  @action getData() {
    let socket = this.socket.io();

    socket.on('data-response', (data) => {
      this.data = data
    })

    socket.emit('data-request');
  }
}
```

```
Note: getData() will triggered in any route modal.
```

I'm new to EmberJS, I didn't find any latest class(oops) based example code.

Also suggest any boilerplate or open source with latest version please.

Comment: first off, Welcome! <3    I think to better help, I need know what the goal is -- how you're calling these functions, etc.

I've done socket stuff a bunch (but not with socket.io) in classes and can help! but I need more information <3

Comment: I have 2 services, one is for socket connection, another for data retrieval. my goal is to make REST API like call in socket io... even if I click (example: User Profile) a link, It should fetch the details from server.

Comment: this seems like an abuse of the concept of web sockets, yeah?

typically, you'd have one socked connection for all requests?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was in server side... My full script is waiting to check authenticated user before listening to the event...

Now I handled and it is working fine....